# No URI present. Default controller set. Codeigniter 3.1.9 and PHP 7.0

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3

My routing is not working.

I removed the index.php with - https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/wiki/Removing-index.php-from-a-URL-path-in-XAMPP-for-Windows

I am using the following settings.  Fresh copy of Codeigniter 3.1.9

**config.php**

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/CodeIgniter-3.1.9/';
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

**.htaccess**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

**routes.php**

```
$route['hello/(:any)'] = 'hello/$1';
```

**controller - Hello.php**

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Hello extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
    }
    public function index()
    {
        echo("Hello - index");
        $this->load->view('welcome_message');
    }

    public function hello(){
        echo("hello");
        $this->load->view('welcome_message');
    }
}
```

When I navigate to http://localhost/CodeIgniter-3.1.9/hello it's loading the Welcome controller.

**Logs**

```
DEBUG - 2018-08-24 18:56:47 --> UTF-8 Support Enabled
DEBUG - 2018-08-24 18:56:47 --> No URI present. Default controller set.
DEBUG - 2018-08-24 18:56:47 --> Global POST, GET and COOKIE data sanitized
DEBUG - 2018-08-24 18:56:47 --> Total execution time: 0.0227
```

Comment: shouldnt you be using the `http://localhost/hello` url?

Comment: That's not the project project path.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the slash at the end of `base_url`

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/CodeIgniter-3.1.9';
```

Answer (score 0):

That's my bad, I turned on `$config['enable_query_strings'] = TRUE;` in config that's why it's causing the issue. When I was reading the core uri.php file then it has following comment.

```
// If query strings are enabled, we don't need to parse any segments.
        // However, they don't make sense under CLI.
        if (is_cli() OR $this->config->item('enable_query_strings') !== TRUE)
```

I set `$config['enable_query_strings'] = FALSE;` then everything working fine.